how to get data from the relationship table in laravel 10?
How do I get the data from a relationship table?
this is the tables' structure:
paradises
    id - integer
    title - string
    travel_interest_id - integer
 
travel_interests
    id - integer
    name - string

and this is my code so far
Models/Paradise.php
    public function travelInterests()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TravelInterest::class);
    }

Models/TravelInterest.php
    public function paradises()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Paradise::class);
    }

in this Controller, I'm getting all the data from the travel_interests table instead of just one record that is associated with the paradise record.
ParadiseController.php
public function show(Paradise $paradise)
{
    dd($paradise->travelInterests->get());
}

what am I doing wrong? any help is appreciated..

$paradise->travelInterests https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

$paradise->travelInterests is a relationship method on your model, you should call it as a method with parentheses.
$paradise->travelInterests()->get();


$paradise->travelInterests is preferred!

@OMiShah $paradise->travelInterests  is preferred if you want to work directly with the relationship without explicitly calling  get(). When you access travelInterests as a property, Eloquent automatically handles fetching the related data for you, making it more convenient and cleaner.
$paradise = Paradise::with('travelInterests')->get(); this one is best to avoid N+1 query problem
